# Problema con App.config al usar "Ñ" en un Windows Service

Tags: c#, app.config

Tengo un App.config y he intentado leer un key desde un Windows Service, el key que intento leer tiene como valor "CONTRASEÑA GENERADA" pero no lo puedo leer debido a que no acepta esos caracteres.

¿Se puede utilizar la "Ñ" como valor para un key en el App.config?

Agradezco su orientación.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 
    <appSettings>
      <add key="CTRGEN" value="CONTRASEÑA GENERADA"/> 
    </appSettings> 
    </connectionStrings>
    </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Cuando intentas leer la configuracion, haces `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CTRCEN"]` o `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONTRASEÑA GENERADA"]`?

Comment: @Einer, para leerlo hago:  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CTRCEN"], ese no es el problema como tal, ese app.config lo leo desde un WindowsService y al momento de iniciarlo se detiene automáticamente por que no puede leerlo debido a la "Ñ"

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el error que te lanza

Comment: Puedes aplicar un XML encode a ese carácter. Sustituye la `Ñ` por `&#209;`

Comment: @Einer El error es: System.Configuration.onfigurationErrorsException: Invalid character in the given encoding.

Comment: Ya lo intenté pero el App.config no lo reconoce como un carácter válido.

Comment: Hola. Es raro... El `app.config` no deja de ser un XML al fin y al cabo. Puedes mostrarnos el mensaje de error?

Comment: Lo mismo pensé, tengo el encoding utf-8, ¿Qué más puede ser?

Comment: Verifica con Notepad++ por ejemplo que la codificación de dicho archivo sea utf8.

Comment: Lo revisé, sí es utf-8

Comment: Es raro... Prueba a cambiar la codificación a `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: Cambié el enconding a "windows-1252" y ya pude iniciar el Windows Service correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Cambié el enconding a "windows-1252" y con ello el Windows Service puede iniciarse correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Abre el archivo en el **Bloc de notas**
2. Ve al menú `Archivo` > `Guardar como...`
3. En el cuadro emergente, en la **Codificación** (al lado del botón "Guardar") cámbiala a `UTF-8` y guarda el archivo.
4. No olvides revisar que la `Ñ` siga ahí.

Con esto homologarás la codificación del archivo con el *encoding* del mismo (la primera línea, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`).